# Is Gym advisable per Islam

Tags: practical-islam

Is Gym ok to do per Islam to gain health benefits?

Or are we hurting to ourself if one do gym.

Additionally, I want to add is Gym ok to do per Unani and or Ayurvedic studies.

Sorry but intention is to seek right knowledge.

What prophet mohd (Pbuh) used to do in health/ exercise aspects.

Comment: It completely depends on your intentions (niyyath) if you do it to keep yourselves healthy then its permissible, but if you do it show off your body or attract opposite gender (namuharram) excluding wife, then it is haram.

Answer (score 1):

Assalamu alaikum

If a Muslim man intends to go to the gym to become healthy then there is no reason for them not to be able to go there as long as adhering to the sharia of course. However in the case of a Muslim woman they should go to a gym which is for women only as not to mix with non-mahram men. I'm not sure if this would also apply if the woman dressed in accordance to the shariah. You may want to ask a sheikh to further clarify it. IslamQA is good. And Allah knows best.

I personally usually just do my own exercises within my own home as a means of staying fit and active, combined with short walking and gardening, also focusing on keeping the brain sharp to read The Qu'ran etc.

This link may also help further with your question:
https://muslim.sg/articles/top-health-and-fitness-tips-from-prophet-muhammad

Salaam